# How to make a multiple IF AND OR function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so sorry if this seems like lazy asking buy I've been trying for an hour and a half and can't figure it out

how do I write this function:

if B2=BUY AND L2 is greater than 0 write positive OR if B2=BUY AND L2 is less than 0 write negative OR if B2 = SELL write nothing

[image: pic]

Comment: Try `=IF(AND(B2="BUY",L2>0),"POSITIVE",IF(AND(B2="BUY",L2<0),"NEGATIVE",IF(B2="SELL","NOTHING","UNSUPPORTED INPUT")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy:

```
=IF(AND(B2="BUY",0<L2),"positive",IF(AND(B2="BUY",L2<0),"negative",IF(B2="SELL","","L2 equals 0 or B2 contains an unexpected value")))
```

Note that even though your sentence contains 'OR' many times, the formula does not because for this purpose you don't need an 'OR'. What you describe with 'OR' in your sentence is actually an ELSE.